# Azure API Management latency of over 5 seconds

Tags: azure-api-management

We're using API Management to execute an always on function app that, in turn, is calling Azure Search. The function app responds within 100 ms (usually well under), but API Management intermittently takes 3 to 8 seconds to process. I've gone through the trace and found the delay is consistently in the backend step in which API Management is processing the results (sample trace for backend below). The returned data in this case is 664 bytes. Does anyone know what may cause this and, more importantly, how to remove this latency?

The Azure API Management instance, function app, and Azure Search are all in the same region.

```
"backend": [
{
    "source": "forward-request",
    "timestamp": "2018-10-11T13:33:54.0578250Z",
    "elapsed": "00:00:00.0005890",
    "data": {
        "message": "Request is being forwarded to the backend service. Timeout set to 300 seconds",
        "request": {
            "method": "GET",
            "url": "https://ommitted.azurewebsites.net/api/HollanderSearch/?hollander=125-222L&websiteId=1&retrieveAllProductNames=false&onlyRetrieveProductNames=true&numRecsToRetrieve  =25&code=%2Fxu1iz0EimDFnOUvhDVaM4ZejfaW7umV3somaIDCeWJYI5RMIfNnNg%3D%3D&keyword=125-222L",
            "headers": [
                {
                    "name": "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
                    "value": "ommitted"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Postman-Token",
                    "value": "9e809f11-6e63-4422-8c3f-d61962cec6ac"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Cache-Control",
                    "value": "no-cache"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Accept",
                    "value": "*/*"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Accept-Encoding",
                    "value": "gzip,deflate"
                },
                {
                    "name": "User-Agent",
                    "value": "PostmanRuntime/7.3.0"
                },
                {
                    "name": "X-Forwarded-For",
                    "value": "omitted"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    "source": "forward-request",
    "timestamp": "2018-10-11T13:33:59.6717259Z",
    "elapsed": "00:00:05.6045857",
    "data": {
        "response": {
            "status": {
                "code": 200,
                "reason": "OK"
            },
            "headers": [
                {
                    "name": "Pragma",
                    "value": "no-cache"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Transfer-Encoding",
                    "value": "chunked"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Content-Encoding",
                    "value": "gzip"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Vary",
                    "value": "Accept-Encoding"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Cache-Control",
                    "value": "no-cache"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Content-Type",
                    "value": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Date",
                    "value": "Thu, 11 Oct 2018 13:33:59 GMT"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Expires",
                    "value": "-1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Set-Cookie",
                    "value": "ARRAffinity=8065e5ea6c0774f598f30cd38416a122cd6afe1af34a15c7f6430e1a0fe9924c;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=omitted-dev.azurewebsites.net"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Server",
                    "value": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0"
                },
                {
                    "name": "X-Powered-By",
                    "value": "ASP.NET"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    "source": "decompressor",
    "timestamp": "2018-10-11T13:33:59.6717259Z",
    "elapsed": "00:00:05.6045976",
    "data": "Content-Encoding header with value `gzip` detected in message headers. Content re-compression may require to correctly apply content modification policies."
}
```

]

Comment: How consistent is this? Azure Functions do have considerable cold-start, i.e. first call to AF is always slower that consequent calls.

Comment: We're having similar issues. The APIM receives a request, then waits for about 0.5 seconds before sending it to the backend. The backend have no cold-starts (always on, dedicated ASP) and executes the request in ~200ms. Total execution times end up around 1.5s from outside APIM, while firing directly on backend executes on around 200ms.

Comment: @RKrogh have you found any good solution for it or you stepped away from APIM?

Comment: @Emil We tried using Azure Premium Functions instead but it didn't really help us. Avg went up but somewhat less of the delays. We are now trying to run on http-based endpoints instead of Azure Functions based. In my head I don't see why this would make a difference but we do seem to have somewhat less delays that way. Nothing clear though, sorry.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue with some requests from a client, but it is very sporadic and I am not being able to reproduce the issue with tracing enabled to check where the delay is. I know for sure that the backend is responding fast (250ms) but the total response time ends up on 3-4 seconds. Any good ideas on how to troubleshoot this?